# How many times same interrupt can be in pending state at a time? (In ARM CM-3)

Tags: arm, driver, linux-device-driver, cortex-m, firmware

Could not find the answer to 
How many times same interrupt can be in pending state at a time? (In ARM CM-3)
e.g. :

We are processing one interrupt INT_RX, at the same time 3 more packets received. so I expect 3 times more this interrupt to appear sequentially. Will it be notified 3 times or once or none?

Comment: No almost never; your interrupt routine should service not just one packet, but all outstanding packets.  It is expensive to handle an interrupt, return and then be immediately interrupted again.  This is the worst case bursting; so your interrupt handler should keep processing if there are additional interrupts.  Details will depends on particular hardware, but for the above reasons it is not good to use it this way unless code space is at a premium.

Comment: what have your experiments shown?

Comment: I posted the same question to arm community also. [link](http://community.arm.com/message/28608). You can check the answer there

Comment: When I did not get the answer to question, I posted the same to arm community
http://community.arm.com/message/28608, you can check it there. 

Everybody is saying, Only one interrupt can be in pended state. But I am able to see more then one, may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If processor doesn't service ISR(interrupt service routine) at first, there's no way to check how many Rx interrupts occurred later. It seems your Rx ISR doesn't work properly or there are too many other INT's are serviced than Rx due to priority.